# How do I build librevenge static libraries (*.lib) for use in Windows?

Tags: build, static-libraries, cross-compiling, gnu-make, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am unable to find a working solution for building the librevenge static libs for Windows.

For wider context, I need to build the librevenge static libraries because this is a dependancy for the libcdr library. I need libcdr to work on 64 bit windows (release) so I need to build librevenge for x64/release.

---

For reference, this is the librevenge project I have cloned from GitHub: https://github.com/Distrotech/librevenge

The librevenge project uses GNU Make to handle the build process and from experimenting I have found I am unable to run the autogen.sh and configure scripts in the Windows Git Bash terminal due to many  errors ranging from syntax issues to multiple missing packages. I can confirm these scripts run correctly on WSL and MacOS just fine with very few problems that were straight forward to resolve after a few google searches. Of course, this is to be expected since Windows is not part of the UNIX family and GNU Make is made to work on UNIX based systems.

**Using Visual Studio**

According to the librevenge README, there are workspaces in build/win32/ where the static libs can be built from the Visual Studio solution files provided. Inside build/win32 I have opened the librevenge.vcxproj.sln in VS2022 and I have changed the solution configurations to output release/x64.

Strangely, there are many source files that are referenced in the librevenge project but of them do not actually exist anywhere in the repo. As expected, the project is unable to be built as a result of this.

[Visual Studio missing source file errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4elC.png)

I have tried checking out to different tags in the librevenge repo for example librevenge-0.0.4, librevenge-0.0.0 etc. and encountering the same errors when attempting to build the VS project.

My assumptions are the visual studio solutions have not been updated to match the source files used in the newer version of librevenge. If this is the case, is there perhaps a workaround I could use to find what source files are needed to successfully compile the librevenge project?

**Using GNU Make in WSL**

An alternative is to use WSL to emulate a linux distrobuiton on my Windows machine. Using the g++ compiler I have successfully compiled the librevenge library in the form of .so files.

I have tried using x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ which is capable of cross-compilation.

Commands:

`./autogen.sh`

No problems here once the correct packages are installed.

`./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --disable-werror`

Has taken some time to work out what parameters are required for cross-compilation but I believe this is getting closer to what I need. So --build is specifying the current environment I am building in and --host is 64 bit Windows which I am building for. I need --disable-werror so that the compiler ignores "unnecessary parathenses" that ceases compilation.

`make`

Here I am encountering a problem where the zlib.h cannot be found even though zlib.h is already installed in usr/include and usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++/include.

I may continue down this route of getting cross-compilation to work but I would much rather have the library built natively in Windows using Visual Studio.

**Summary**

Going forward, please may I have some pointers on either building librevenge in Visual Studio or WSL. As I said previously, I would rather build librevenge on Visual Studio since this would make building for Windows straight forward in future.

Comment: [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) has prebuilt libcdr in its package manager, but that's for MinGW, not Visual Studio. MSYS2 also can run `make` properly, but it's probably of little use to you, since I doubt their makefiles support MSVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to build librevenge on Windows is to use the provided Visual Studio project in the repository and fixing the errors (removing the missing files).

Steps to build librevenge:

1. Clone the repo @ https://github.com/Distrotech/librevenge.
2. Git checkout to latest librevenge release tag.
3. Go to librevenge/build/win32 and open librevenge.vcxproj.sln.
4. Attempt to build the librevenge project and you will see a bunch of errors.
5. Remove all the missing .cpp and .h files in the Solution Explorer (there are quite a few).
6. Go to configuration manager and create new x64 solution platform.
7. Add include file path to boost for the librevenge project (for all configs and platforms).
8. Build librevenge project in chosen target platform.
9. The static lib will apear in \librevenge\build\win32\Release\lib for win32 platform and \librevenge\build\win32\Release\lib.

I hope this helps someone!